# CSS font smoothing

Tags: html, css

The font looks distorted on different browsers except chrome.

At first I had two google web fonts attached, Montserrat and open sans. it looked great on chrome, but when I checked it on firefox and safari the montserrat font looked all crappy and distorted, after looking up for more than an hour I found nothing useful so to make things work I removed montserrat and adjusted open sans in place of it (I know),

so now open sans looks good but only in small size as soon as I increase the size of the font it gives that same crispness that it gave to montserrat, which I dont want!
I like it the way chrome displays,
What should I do please help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what `font-smoothing` property are you using in your css?

Comment: none. is there any property like that?

Answer (score 2):

Your sites never to look the same in different browsers or operating systems, they are using different architecture all have different conception on what is preferred.

Also don't bloat your css by tweak your css to adapt variety of classes for different browsers

But you can **try** with code below:

```css
font{
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.004);
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
}
```